# Prototype JS: Document.observe fires "undefined is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I try to use the Event.observe method which is provided by Prototype JS. To be sure that the DOM is loaded, I use document.observe. This causes the error **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**. Prototype JS was loaded as you can see below:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>playground</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/prototype.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../js/functions.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <a href="#" id="meinLink">Hello World</a>
    </div>
    <input type="button" onclick="changeLinkText()" value="Change link by using Prototype">
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
//this works
var changeLinkText = function(){
    $("meinLink").innerHTML="prototypeWorks";
};

//this causes the error
Document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $("meinLink").observe('click', function(e) {
        document.getElementById('meinLink').innerHTML="prototypeDoesntWork";
    });
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `Document` and not `document`? Using the correct thing, it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RYmyx/. `Document` is the interface, `document` is the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `D` in

```
Document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
```

is upper-case, fixing it to it's correct notation

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
```

will probably do the job.

You can also try to [invoke](http://prototypejs.org/doc/1.6.0/enumerable/invoke.html) an on-click-event listener.

```
$$('meinLink').invoke('on', 'click', '.item', function(event, el) {
    // el is the 'meinLink' element
});
```

It's even possible that just using [on](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) will do the job.

```
$("meinLink").on("click", function(event) {
   document.getElementById('meinLink').innerHTML="prototypeDoesntWork";
});
```